# Is there value in harmonizing tags between sites?

Tags: discussion, tags, migration, site-crossover

There is currently a [discussion](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4417/the-tag-orthodoxism-is-not-orthodox) on History Meta over what to do about the ambiguous and/or nonstandard [[orthodoxism]](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/orthodoxism) tag. One of the proposed ideas (mine actually) is to rename it [eastern-orthodox] in order to harmonize it with the equivalent [[eastern-orthodox]](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/eastern-orthodox) tag on Christianity Stack Exchange, which it appears to match up to in terms of usage.

Generally speaking, is there value in seeking to harmonize the names of tags *across sites* when there is consensus that they relate to the same underlying thing or concept?

There are quite a few examples across the network where the same tag concept appears to be named differently on different sites:

- Mi Yodeya's [[Mabul]](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mabul) versus Christianity SE's [[Flood of Noah]](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/flood-of-noah)
- Mi Yodeya's [[Abraham]](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/abraham) versus Islam SE's [[Prophet Ibrahim]](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/prophet-ibrahim)
- Mi Yodeya's [[Noach Noah the Man]](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/noach-noah-the-man) versus Islam SE's [[Prophet Nuh]](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/prophet-nuh)
- Mi Yodeya's [[Genesis-Bereishith]](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/genesis-bereishith) versus Biblical Hermeneutics SE's [[Genesis]](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/genesis)
- Literature SE's [[Cthulhu]](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cthulhu) versus Science Fiction and Fantasy SE's [[Cthulhu Mythos]](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cthulhu-mythos)
- Movies and TV SE's [[Star Trek the Next Generation]](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-trek-the-next-generation) versus Science Fiction and Fantasy SE's [[Star Trek TNG]](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-trek-tng)
- Travel SE's [[Russia]](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/russia) versus Politics SE's [[Russian Federation]](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/russian-federation).

Before anyone asks, I know that the question scope of these tags is different, for example, a question about the documents necessary to land a private yacht in Vladivostok and posted on Politics SE under the tag [Russian-Federation] is off-topic due to not being about politics, but it is clearly a question about *Russia* and so maps directly to Travel SE's [Russia] tag, where the question will most likely be on-topic. Thus, harmonizing tag spelling would seem to be a boon for migration and make migrating questions easier. I'm not sure, though, whether question migration is common enough that spending the time to harmonize tags is worth it.

Just to be clear, I am talking about cases where the underlying subject matter of the tag matches that of another site rather than the scope of allowed questions that concern that subject matter. For example, if one site allows questions about programming Marklar, another on using Marklar in the classroom, and another on the history of Marklar, should we allow one of those sites to decide to name their tag by the lesser-known but valid synonym [Mark System Technology LAR]?

So, is harmonizing tags something that is worth it? If so, how should we coordinate the project? If not, is it because it just isn't worth the effort or would it cause active harm?

Comment: I'd say so only if a normal user migration path currently exists from one site to the other, or is likely to exist in the near future (a pending request for it has been highly upvoted or is tagged [tag:status-review]). Migrations done by moderators are exempt from the tags rule, and the destination site can easily change the tag.

Comment: Also I wouldn't dare steering into naming on the religion sites, they might refer to the same concept, but naming matters. People will get confused when the regularly used name isn't found in the tags list.

Comment: While I can imagine many tag names shared between, e.g., programming/technical Stacks, I'd be shocked if less than 75% of the tags on [worldbuilding.se] didn't align with any other Stack - even if the subject matter was highly correlated.